# Error #1093 - Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I'm trying to delete duplicate rows in a table. The email field needs to be be unique in the table for the code after it to run.  Here's my code:

```
DELETE FROM deleteRequests
    WHERE Email NOT IN (
        SELECT MAX(Email)
        FROM deleteRequests
        GROUP BY email);
```

The error I get is: '#1093 - Table 'deleteRequests' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data'

I think the problem is that I'm using mariadb 10.2 (which also means I can't use WITH CTE).  I am not in control of updating this, so I need a workaround.  Suggestions?

Comment: Your query is non-sensical.  It will delete no rows, ever (well, I suppose there could be a race condition where a new email is inserted during the course of the query and a dirty read).

Comment: Something about your logic looks odd...but you can use a join instead of a not in.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL, MariaDB doesn't allow the table to be referenced again in a `DELETE` or `UPDATE`.  An easy work-around is to use a `JOIN`:

```
DELETE dr
    FROM deleteRequests dr LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT MAX(email) as max_email
          FROM deleteRequests
          GROUP BY email
         ) dr2
         ON dr2.email = dr.max_email
    WHERE dr2.max_email IS NOT NULL;
```

Of course, this query is non-sensical because you are aggregating by `email` and choosing the max -- so all non-`NULL` emails will match.

Perhaps you want `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` in the subquery,.

Comment: So I changed my approach and added an ID to each record.  Now the code I have is: `DELETE dr
    FROM deleteRequests dr LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT MAX(mamaID) as maxID
          FROM deleteRequests
          GROUP BY mamaID
         ) dr2
         ON dr2.maxID = dr.mamaID;`
Doing this deletes all my records.

Comment: @KristiPerkins . . . I think I pointed that out in the answer.  But this answers the question you asked, which was a question about syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new table to work from.

```
CREATE TABLE deleteRequestsWorking as
SELECT MAX(mamaID) as mamaID, Email
          FROM deleteRequests
          GROUP BY mamaID;
```

This gave me the table I needed, and so instead of trying to get it to update my original table by using a `LEFT JOIN` and `DELETE`, I just used it.  They're both temporary tables that get deleted at the end of the process, so it works.